# Ubuntu 15.04/kernel 4.0.1, tpm error (7) occured

Tags: kernel, 15.04, bug-reporting, tpm

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04. Once I had installed all updates, I ran into this error:

```
[  4.124110] tpm_tis 00:00: A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr (I took a picture but it blurs the rest of the error)
starting version 219
```

This error does not seem to interrupt start-up, but this error does occur after an unsuccessful startup (When I press power button, it starts, turns purple and shortly after black, and the fans go to low speed)

I do not have an Nvidia graphics card, I have ATI radeon HD 3200  (no drivers for any newer kernels)

What I have tried:

- Reinstall ubuntu
- delete everything associated with nvidia
- updated kernel to 4.0.1
- update, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I have googled this, but none of the solutions worked for me. And most of them were about a nvidia card causing this error.

Also, after booting into empty, Ubuntu loading takes forever (over 2minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over been having a similar problem. I found out that Linux and ubuntu sometimes forget to re-install the cpu. Try...

```
sudo apt-get install cpu
```

It helped my laptop after I figured that out. Additionally you should   uninstall any kernels that you aren't using